# IronPython string split

Tags: python

I have full path of the file and I need to get the file name alone. Please suggest.

```
path = 'C:\Users\Desktop\New folder\10Jul14_14706pm\file.txt'
```

expected result, `filename = file.txt`

Comment: `path.split(r'\')[-1]`

Comment: Why not use the routines in `os.path` or `System.IO.Path`?

Comment: On python 3 that would be an invalid string unless it's a raw string for a start

Comment: path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\New folder\10Jul14_14706pm\file.txt'
path.split('\\')[-1]

Comment: What's that? A working answer? Then post it as an answer, please

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for your inputs,

```
path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\New folder\10Jul14_14706pm\file.txt'
path.split('\\')[-1]
```

Returns `file.txt`

Comment: retu_rn_s. Three backslashes don't work in Python 2.7

Comment: Its double backslashes only...But if i enter double slash, it is truncated in this site display....